# Appreciate some help from IntelliJ users : Importing eclipse project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

I followed almost all the standard steps suggested by Jetbrains for importing an eclipse project into IntelliJ, without any success. I get about 100 erros, and all related to some imports related to Java. for eg.

```
Error:(59, 50) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class com.comprion.android.js.GPSystem
Error:(59, 62) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Scriptable
location: class com.comprion.android.js.GPSystem
Error:(76, 82) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Scriptable
location: class com.comprion.android.js.GPSystem
Error:(76, 70) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Context
location: class com.comprion.android.js.GPSystem
Error:(23, 30) java: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
Error:(24, 30) java: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
Error:(76, 117) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Function
location: class com.comprion.android.js.GPSystem
Error:(28, 31) java: cannot find symbol
symbol: class ScriptableObject
Error:(59, 97) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Function
location: class com.comprion.android.js.GPSystem
Error:(25, 30) java: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
Error:(26, 30) java: package org.mozilla.javascript does not exist
}
```

(and many more)

It know its something simple and small & tricky thing i might be missing. I would really appreciate some help from IntelliJ users.

I Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you did not import Android SDK or some custom library in `lib` directory or even imported some library project.

Android SDK: `File -> Project Structure -> SDKs` and see if the right Android SDK is imported.  You have to import Java as well. Look how it looks in my IDE.

[image]

Lib JAR files: Open the project's `lib` directory, right click on any JAR file and press `Add as Library...`.

If you still have errors (I am sure the number will decrease), then go to a specific error and check its path. It may be that you did not import some 3rd party Library project. You can do that again via `Project Structure`, but this time go to `Modules` and then `Add/Import` the missing library.